An inequality about binomial distribution
Statement
Assume that $\sigma,R\in (1,+\infty)$, $N\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $p\in (0,1)$, $n_1\in\{0,1,2,\cdots,N-1\}$. Prove or disprove that
$$B^\frac{1}{\sigma}(n_1)-B^\frac{1}{\sigma}(n_1+1)<1 .$$
Here, the function $B$ is defined as
$$ B(n_1):=\sum_{n_2=0}^{N-n_1}\binom{N-n_1}{n_2}p^{n_2}(1-p)^{N-n_1-n_2}\left(n_2+(N-n_1-n_2)R^{\frac{1}{\sigma}-1}\right)^\sigma .$$
My attempts
First I tried using the inequality $B^\frac{1}{\sigma}(n_1)-B^\frac{1}{\sigma}(n_1+1)<\left(B(n_1)-B(n_1+1)\right)^\frac{1}{\sigma}$ since $\sigma>1$, but $\left(B(n_1)-B(n_1+1)\right)^\frac{1}{\sigma}$ may be greater than 1 (concluded by computer). So this approach may not work.Then, I tried using $\binom{N-n_1}{n_2}=\binom{N-n_1-1}{n_2}+\binom{N-n_1-1}{n_2-1}$, but I still haven't proven it.
So how to prove or disprove this inequality? Thanks in advance!
Update
Thanks to a user who answered earlier (he may have deleted his answer because of a slight error in his argument), I can transform the left side of the inequality to be proved into a form that is more probabilistic.
Equivalent proposition: Assume that the random variables $X_1, X_2,\cdots , X_n (n\ge 1)$ are independent and identically distributed, with $\operatorname{P}(X_k=1)=p,\operatorname{P}(X_{k}=t)=1-p$, where $p,t\in (0,1)$. Real number $\sigma > 1$. Prove that
$$ \operatorname{E}^{\frac{1}{\sigma}}\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k\right)^\sigma\right] - \operatorname{E}^{\frac{1}{\sigma}}\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}X_k\right)^\sigma\right] < 1 .$$
P.S. Actually, $t=R^{\frac{1}{\sigma}-1}$ and $n=N-n_1$.

Another try, now I claim that the inequality holds.
For a random variable $X$, denote $\|X\|=(\mathbb E |X|^\sigma)^{1/\sigma}$. It is indeed a norm.
Then
$$
\|X_1+\ldots+X_n\|\leqslant \|X_1+\ldots+X_{n-1}\|+\|X_n\|\leqslant
\|X_1+\ldots+X_{n-1}\|+1.
$$

Thank you for your reply! But I think $T$ should be less than $1$. Since $\frac{1}{\sigma}<1$, so $\frac{1}{\sigma}-1<0$, and therefore $T=R^{\frac{1}{\sigma}-1}<1$. So the inequality to be proven is true when $\sigma=1$.

Please check another attempt, with another answer. I am not certain about proofs, but at least one of two answers is correct.

Very concise and elegant proof! Thank you!

This problem can be generalized, the details are described here (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/484304/an-inequality-about-binomial-distribution-generalization). I turn to you for assistance. Thank you!
